# Kotlin app not running after adding dependencies

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, dagger-hilt, build-error

I am trying to build an application using coroutines, dagger and mvvm. I have just added the required the dependencies but I am getting the following error when I am trying to run on my device.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

build.gradle.kts(Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1")
    }
}
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.0" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
}
```

build.gradle (app)

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.tweetify"
    compileSdk = 34

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.tweetify"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.0"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}



dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

    // hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha")

    // ViewModels
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.7.0")

    // Coroutines
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:2.7.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kotlinx-coroutines-android:2.7.0")

    // Retrofit
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")

    // Navigation
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:2.7.7")
}
```

The project is getting cleaned successfully but it gives this kind of error when I try to run it.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Please share the full log from that Gradle sync

Answer (score 0):

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    // Add other repositories if needed
}
```

add this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
```

and change the hilt too some hilt dependency not working with kotlin core 1.12.0

```
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.45")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.45")
```

add classpath for hilt too with same version 2.45

and read the crash carefully

Comment: Made the changes, but the same error persists !

Comment: did u apply gradle classpath , if u did try to sync the project in online mode not offline